# Insert png image programatically in pdf file at specific location

Tags: python, shell, pdf, png

Looking for easiest way to do the following:

- I have created 10,000 unique QR-codes, with unique filenames.
- I have one postcard design (.ai, eps, pdf - doesn't matter) with place holder for the qr code and for a the unique filename (sans .png extension).

How would I go about inserting each of the 10.000 png's into 10,000 copies of the pdf files? (and I need to do the same with the unique filename /textstring that represents each QR code).

since I am really no good with programming it' doesn't matter which tools to use. As long as you hold my hand - or there is a link to a beginners documentation.

however:
I am trying to learn python - so that is preferred.
I work a little bit with R - but that will not be the easiest solution.
If this can be done directly from the terminal with a shell script then halliluja :-)

But really - if you know of a solution - then please post it, regardless of the tools.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in Python using pyPdf to merge documents.
Basically, you create a PDF with your QRCode placed where you want it in the end.

You can use the (c)StringIO module to store the created PDF file in memory.

You can [find pyPDF here](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/); there's an example that shows how you would add a watermark to a file, you should be following the same logic.

Comment: Haven't done it yet - but this looks really good. Will accept for now. Thanks a lot Thomas.